# SingleChildScrollView isn't working in my login screen

Tags: flutter

this is the login screen I had Implemented using flutter. I want this screen to be scrollable. how can I do that? I have uploaded my login screen code for your reference. I have tried out my column wrap with a single-child scroll view.  but it doesn't work. there are multiple columns, maybe I'm wrapping the wrong column. I appriciate your help on this.

[image]

```
  class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 86, 124), Color(0xff141a3a)],
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            )),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 20, right: 20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      //  Spacer(flex: 1),
                      Image(
                        image: const AssetImage(
                          'assets/images/LogoVector.png',
                        ),
                        height: Size.width / 2.9,
                        width: Size.width / 2.9,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5),
                      Text(
                        "LOGIN",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            color: textWhite,
                            fontFamily: "Roboto"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                // const Spacer(flex: 1),
                const Expanded(flex: 3, child: Center(child: LoginForm())),
               
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginFormState createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

Map<String, String> loginUserData = {
  'email': '',
  'password': '',
  'id': '',
  'userName': '',
  'token': '',
  'userStatus': '',
};

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  TextEditingController emailEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String email = "";
  String password = "";
  String username = "";
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool typing = true;
  bool _isObscure = true;




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: emailEditingController,
            enabled: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  color: textWhite,
                ),
                // borderSide: BorderSide.none
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: textWhite),
              ),

              errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
              ),
              focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
              ),
              isDense: true,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 30, 10, 0),

              hintText: "Email/ Username",
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: textWhite, fontFamily: "Roboto", fontSize: 14),
            ),
            style: TextStyle(color: textWhite),
            validator: (String? UserName) {
              if (UserName != null && UserName.isEmpty) {
                return "Email can't be empty";
              }
              return null;
            },
            onChanged: (String? text) {
              email = text!;
              // print(email);
            },
            onSaved: (value) {
              loginUserData['email'] = value!;
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: passwordEditingController,
            obscureText: _isObscure,
            enabled: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: textWhite),
                  //  borderSide: BorderSide.none
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: textWhite),
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                ),
                focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                ),
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                        _isObscure ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
                    color: textWhite,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _isObscure = !_isObscure;
                      });
                    }),
                hintText: "Password",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: textWhite,
                  fontFamily: "Roboto",
                  fontSize: 14,
                )),
            style: TextStyle(color: textWhite),
            validator: (String? Password) {
              if (Password != null && Password.isEmpty) {
                return "Password can't be empty";
              }
              return null;
            },
            onChanged: (String? text) {
              password = text!;
              print(password);
            },
            onSaved: (value) {
              loginUserData['password'] = value!;
            },
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                  title: const Text(
                    "Remember Me",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: textWhite, fontFamily: "Roboto", fontSize: 14),
                  ),
                  activeColor: buttontext,
                  // tileColor: buttontext,

                  value: checkedValue,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                    setState(() {
                      if (isLoading != true) {
                        checkedValue = newValue!;
                        print(newValue);
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, top: 0),
                  controlAffinity:
                  ListTileControlAffinity.leading, //  <-- leading Checkbox
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: Text(
                  "Forget Password",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: textWhite, fontFamily: "Roboto", fontSize: 14),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Get.to(() => Forget_Screen());
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 40),
          isLoading
              ? SpinKitDualRing(
            color: textWhite,
            size: 40,
          )
              : GestureDetector(
            child: MainButton("Login"),
            onTap: () async {
              FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                _formKey.currentState!.save();
                await LoginData();
                // Get.to(BottomNavigation());
              }
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          Container(
            width: 275.0,
            height: 40.0,
            child: OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Get.to(() => const Signup_Screen());
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Signup',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15, fontFamily: "Roboto", color: textWhite
                  //fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  // color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                side: const BorderSide(
                  width: 1.0,
                  color: textWhite,
                ),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
               
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap everything under the `Scaffold`:

```
Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 20, right: 20),
            child: Column(
            ........
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not see you using the `SingleChildScrollView` in then code sample you have provided with.

But if you want to make the page scrollable, Wrap the child of the scaffold in the SingleChildScrollView

```
Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
....
```